# Permission denied (publickey) when cloning Repo from Gitlab.com on my Rasperry Pi

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

I'm trying to clone a repo from Gitlab.com via ssh. But I get this error all the time:

```
pi@prometheus:~/work/repos$ git clone git@gitlab.com:sommerfeld.sebastian/prometheus-grafana.git
Cloning into 'prometheus-grafana'...
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I created a SSH key this way:

```
keyName="$1"
keyFile="/home/$USER/.ssh/$keyName.key"

echo -e "$LOG_INFO Create new ssh key: $keyName"
cd ~/.ssh || exit
ssh-keygen -f "$keyFile" -t ed25519 -C "sommerfeld.sebastian@gmail.com"

echo -e "$LOG_INFO Start the ssh-agent in background"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"

echo -e "$LOG_INFO Add ssh key to the ssh-agent"
ssh-add "$keyFile"

echo -e "$LOG_DONE Key created"
```

I added the public key to Gitlab.com (User Settings > SSH Keys > KEYNAME). Still I get this error all the time.

The error occurs on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Server 21.04 64-bit. The same scripts work on my regular workstation running Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 64-bit.

Debug output from my RasPi running `ssh -v git@gitlab.com`:

```
pi@prometheus:~/work/repos$ ssh -v git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/pi/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/pi/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
```

I don't see, why my RasPi behaves differently than my Ubuntu workstation. Same command on my workstation returns a different result printing `Welcome to GitLab, @sommerfeld.sebastian!` a couple of lines before the end.

SSH Version on my RasPi:

```
pi@prometheus:~/work/repos$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you used for the `$keyFile` in your script.

A default name should be part of the `/home/pi/.ssh/id_xxx` names considered during an SSH session.
But a non-default name would need to be specified in an `~/.ssh/config`: double-check if you have one.

Also, in your script, to be sure, don't use `~/.ssh,` but `/home/$USER/.ssh` consistently, to avoid any mistake when the shell substitutes `~`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped ... I'm still a little confused because with my Ubuntu laptop I use a key namend "gitlab.key" and "gitlab.key.pub" without an additional ~/.ssh/config file. But using this file did the trick for my raspi. Don't know why the two behave differently but again: it works

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld OK. You can do a `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` on your Ubuntu laptop, to see what is actually used there, and why `$HOME/.ssh/gitlab.key` works there.

Comment: Thanks ... I guess the line `Found key in /home/sebastian/.ssh/known_hosts:13` is a hint to why this works in my laptop.

Comment: @SebastianSommerfeld That just means it knows of the destination server, not that it can access it, as illustrated by https://serverfault.com/q/571158/783.